# Align amsmath multline to top of item in enumerate

Tags: align, amsmath

I am writing a simple pseudocode stub using `amsmath` (do not need `algorithmic` package) as follows in an enumerated list item, however it shows up a couple of lines below the item bullet, how can I align it to the level of bullet ?

```
begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item \begin{multline*}s=0\\
for\; i=1\; to\; n\\
\quad for\; j=i\; to\; n\\
\quad if(A[i] > A[j])\; then\; s = s+1\\
return\; s\\
\end{multline*}
\end{enumerate}
```

This produces something as follows:

```
(a)

      s =0
        for i = 1 to n
           for j = i to n
              if (A[i] > A[j]) then s = s + 1
       returns
```

How can I align `s=0` to level of `a`.

Comment: not an answer, but a comment on the input.  this is code, not really math, and thus shouldn't be italic.    the words can be wrapped in `\text{...}`, and the whole second line would be better as `\text{for $i=1$ to $n$}`. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're not breaking this code stub across the page boundary. As such there is no reason why you need a mathematical alignment environment; you can set it in a `tabular` that is aligned at the `[t]`op with the enumeration label:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newenvironment{codestub}[1][t]
  {\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}}
  {\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\cind}{\hspace*{1em}}% ...or \quad, or some other length

% Some language/keyword definitions
\newcommand{\kw}{\textbf}
\newcommand{\FOR}{\kw{for}}
\newcommand{\TO}{\kw{to}}
\newcommand{\IF}{\kw{if}}
\newcommand{\THEN}{\kw{then}}
\newcommand{\RETURN}{\kw{return}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \item
    \begin{codestub}
      $s = 0$ \\
      for $i = 1$ to $n$ \\
      \cind for $j = i$ to $n$ \\
      \cind\cind if $(A[i] > A[j])$ then $s = s + 1$ \\
      return $s$
    \end{codestub}

  \item
    \begin{codestub}
      $s = 0$ \\
      \FOR{} $i = 1$ \TO{} $n$ \\
      \cind \FOR{} $j = i$ \TO{} $n$ \\
      \cind\cind \IF{} $(A[i] > A[j])$ \THEN{} $s = s + 1$ \\
      \RETURN{} $s$
    \end{codestub}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Item (a) replicates your requirements, while (b) suggests an output that typically matches pseudocode where keywords are highlighted for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `multlined` environment, from `mathtools` (needless to load `amsmath` in this case). However, you'll obtain a nicer result with a dedicated package such as `algorithmic`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}%
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage[noend]{algorithmic} %

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \item $ \begin{multlined}[t]s=0\\
        \text{for}\; i=1\; \text{to}\; n\\
        \quad \text{for}\; j=i\; to\; n\\
        \quad \text{if}(A[i] > A[j])\; \text{then}\; s = s+1\\
        \text{return}\; s\\
  \end{multlined} $

  \item %
        \begin{algorithmic}
          \STATE  $ s ∶= q 0 $
          \FOR{$i=0$ \TO $n$}
          %\IF{some condition is true}
          \IF{$ (A[i] > A[j]) $}
          \STATE  $ s ∶= q s + 1 $
          \RETURN{ $ s $}
          \ENDIF
          \ENDFOR
        \end{algorithmic}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]